# InnoDB Select and Update at the same time with LIMIT 1000

Tags: sql, mysql

i have an SQL Select here:

```
SELECT id, pricehistory, pricehistory_timestamp, price, siteid, last_pricecheck FROM `items` ORDER BY `last_pricecheck` ASC LIMIT 1000
```

There i select the last 1000 items, that ordered by last_pricecheck, so the items with oldes pricecheck will run first.

Because i use the same .py multiple times, i want to set last_pricecheck on that 1000 items set to an date 9999-99-99 or a very high date, so they will not be catched again from a second screen that runs the .py again.

How can i Update the 1000 Items that i have selected there and the the last_pricecheck to a higher date that they will be not grabed by next screen...

Any ideas? I tried a few things that i found already but they doesnt work on my innodb

My idea was something like that:

```
SELECT @id:= id, ... FROM items ORDER BY `last_pricecheck` ASC 
LIMIT 1000;
UPDATE items SET last_pricecheck = '2030-01-01 23:59:59'
WHERE id = @id;
```

Comment: Order by and limit works in update clause, in MySQL.

Comment: @SalmanA Remark. This is true only for single-table UPDATE. ORDER BY and LIMIT are not applicable for multiple-table UPDATE..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `order by` clause as if nothing happened:

```
create table foo(bar int, lorem int);

insert into foo(bar)
values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

update foo
set lorem = bar
order by bar
limit 2;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b12071/1